# Resource replacement when changing the db_option_group in the rds resource

Tags: cloud, terraform, rds, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

I use Terraform by Hashicorp to manage AWS infrastructure. Some migration tasks require renaming of several resources such as the db_option_group.

I have no clue why Terraform says "forces replacement" by just renaming the db_option_group. On the API documentation it says that "description" is an optional attribute and no replacement is required.

```
  # module.db_instance.aws_db_option_group.db-option-group must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_db_option_group" "db-option-group" {
      ~ arn                      = "arn:aws:rds:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxx:xx:xxxxx-xx-xxxx-cc01-sqlserver-se-14-00" -> (known after apply)
        engine_name              = "sqlserver-se"
      ~ id                       = "xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-cc01-sqlserver-se-14-00" -> (known after apply)
        major_engine_version     = "14.00"
        name                     = "xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-cc01-sqlserver-se-14-00"
      + name_prefix              = (known after apply)
      ~ option_group_description = "xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-cc01-sqlserver-se-14-00" -> "Option group for xxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-cc01" # forces replacement
      ~ tags                     = {
          + "Project"        = "xxxxx"
          + "ProjectId"      = "xxxxx"
          + "global.app"     = "xxxxx"
          + "global.cbp"     = "xxxxx"
          + "global.dcs"     = "xxxxx"
          + "global.env"     = "qa"
          + "global.opco"    = "xxxxx"
          + "global.project" = "xxxxx"
        }
```

What causes Terraform to behave like this?

Comment: It's possible that this is a bug or AWS API requires deleting the resource and re-adding it if the optional `option_group_description` argument is changed. I've seen this before for optional arguments for other resources. You should create a ticket with the aws provider to be certain.

Comment: I created one: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/12268

Comment: I replied on the issue but you can't modify the description of an RDS option group so Terraform is forced to destroy and recreate if you tell it to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the AWS API does currently not support the possibility to change renaming in-place. You must log into your AWS Accounts and manually adjust the name. Then you may import the resource into the terraform state file.